# Page reloads after submitting the 2captcha token

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, 2captcha

I'm trying to signup on twitter using selenium and using 2captcha API to solve the captcha but for some reason when clicking continue the page refreshes and doesn't proceed

```
        captchaInput = twitter_driver.find_element_by_id('g-recaptcha-response')
        print("Text area set to visible")
        twitter_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:visible;');", captchaInput)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Entering captcha token")
        captchaInput.send_keys(captcha_token)
        time.sleep(5)
        button_click = "javascript:document.getElementById('continue_button').click();"
        twitter_driver.execute_script(button_click)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answering my own question just for records, twitter uses callback captcha so unsolved captcha reloads the page even if you click on the submit button via JS

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/2captcha/2ee70fa1130e756e1693a5d4be4d8c70) helped me solving the captcha issue

Answer (score 0):

if you write on Python try to do so

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#your selector'))).click()
```

there very good all written [https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#:~:text=content%20%3D%20driver.find_element_by_css_selector(%27p.content%27)](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#:%7E:text=content%20%3D%20driver.find_element_by_css_selector(%27p.content%27))

if at your don`t try describe the error in more detail

Comment: The element was hidden so i used JS to click on it and again on another hand I also tried 
```button = twitter_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='continue_button']")
        twitter_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:visible;')", button)```
and then click on it

Comment: use always css selector

Comment: I can't access this element using css selector as it's display is none and it raises the `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: that's right it won't do anything because it's hidden

Comment: it get's visible once I solve the captcha manually, I think this is one of the [callback captcha](https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#callback) if it is then i need to find the callback function

Comment: then you need to first make a condition for the element to become visible, then click it

Comment: I know but the captcha thing needs to be solved via script so i can click on the continue button